# from gojs convert json model to xml

Tags: javascript, xml, json, gojs

I am using gojs to create a class diagram and get the json model data, i understand you can read it from xml, is there a way of writing it to xml with XML DOM? Thank you

jQuery.ajax({
      url: "class.xml",
      success: load,
      dataType: "xml"
    });

function load(x) {
    var xml = jQuery(x.xml ? x.xml : x);
    classd.model = new go.GraphLinksModel(xml.find("node").toArray(), xml.find("link").toArray());

}

Answer (score 0):

GoJS only supports reading and writing to JSON models by default. If you want to read and write XML you need to use regular JavaScript Objects and implement your own persistence from and to XML.

There is a *very* simplistic example of loading from XML here: http://gojs.net/latest/samples/minimalXML.html

It does:

```
    // The previous initialization is the same as the minimal.html sample.
    // Here we request XML-format text data from the server, in this case from a static file.
    jQuery.ajax({
      url: "minimal.xml",
      success: load,
      dataType: "xml"
    });
  }

  function load(x) {
    // ought to handle parse errors here:
    var xml = jQuery(x.xml ? x.xml : x);
    // this does direct binding to XML DOM elements:
    myDiagram.model = new go.GraphLinksModel(xml.find("node").toArray(), xml.find("link").toArray());
    // such binding is read-only at the current time
  }
```